# When onClick display some text in the inputtext

Tags: apex, visualforce

Here is the very basic functionlity that I wanted to test, so when the user click on the checkbox I want to populate some text in the inputtext

When clicked the checkbox but nothing is displaying on the inputtext.

here is my vfp code:

```
<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!myCheckbox}">
    <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" reRender="none" action="{!setDatetime}"/>
</apex:inputCheckbox>

<apex:inputText value="{!inputText1}"/>
```

Controller:

```
public String inputText1 { get; set; }
public Boolean myCheckbox { get; set; }

public PageReference setDatetime() 
{
    if(myCheckbox)
        inputText1  = 'checked';
    else
       inputText1  = 'not checked';
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set id in rerender section. Currently you have set `none` which doesn't exist. I have set it to `checkbox1`

```
<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!myCheckbox}">
    <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" reRender="checkbox1" action="{!setDatetime}"/>
</apex:inputCheckbox>

<apex:inputText id="checkbox1" value="{!inputText1}"/>
```

Comment: i would like to do in on the server side and i have other things to validate before i display the inputtext.

Comment: The solution from Ashwani seems to be correct. The SetDateTime() method is in controller and you can do any server side validation if you like and then set the text accordingly. I am not sure what else is needed as part of this question.

Comment: @AbuHmzah it is already server side as given in other comment.